# SCNNode scale resets when animation plays using a dae file

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I am currently trying to use a dae file in scenekit for my model as well as my animations. When I try to scale the model, it initially scales correctly. After the animation starts playing, it resets to the original scale. Here is what I am trying to do at the moment:

```
    let sceneView = SCNView()

    sceneView.frame = self.view.bounds

    sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()



    self.view.addSubview(sceneView)



    //Add stuff to scene view

    let scene = SCNScene()

    sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true

    sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true

    sceneView.scene = scene



    if let assetScene = SCNScene(named: "halfCircle.dae") {



        if let node = assetScene.rootNode.childNodeWithName("pTorus1", recursively: true) {

            node.scale = SCNVector3(x: 0.2, y: 0.2, z: 0.2)

            scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)

        }
    }
```

Any idea what is going on here?
Thanks.